# QueryDSL query not cast to object

Tags: querydsl

I am querying with QueryDSL from a SQLServer. The beans are generated at build time using maven. Everything runs fine until I try to convert the results to the objects themselves.

```
@RequestMapping("getAbsenceCauses")
public List<CauseOfAbsences> getAbsenceCauses() {

    SQLTemplates templates = new SQLServerTemplates();
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration(templates);
    SQLQueryFactory queryFactory = new SQLQueryFactory(configuration, dataSource);

    CauseOfAbsences absence = new CauseOfAbsences("c");
    List<CauseOfAbsences> absenceCauses = queryFactory.from(absence).list(absence);
    return absenceCauses;
}
```

At runtime I am getting the following exception:
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: RelationalPath based projection can only be used with generated Bean types`

Another post says I would have to "
You need to generate bean types as described [here](http://blog.mysema.com/2011/01/querying-in-sql-with-querydsl.html) under Bean class generation."

But these beans are generated by maven. Is there any thing I can do to tell maven to generate these types? at the moment I am generating like documented:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
    <artifactId>querydsl-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>export</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <jdbcDriver>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</jdbcDriver>
      <jdbcUrl>jdbc:sqlserver://T00-STEMIG.some.where:1433;databaseName=Test</jdbcUrl>
      <packageName>net.neobp.neo.query</packageName>
      <targetFolder>${project.basedir}/target/generated-sources/java</targetFolder>
      <jdbcUser>user</jdbcUser>
      <jdbcPassword>pass</jdbcPassword>
      <schemaPattern>dbo</schemaPattern>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </plugin>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, found it myself:

In the documentation there is a hint on some other parameters that can be configured. I found the exportBeans property, which indicates to generate the objects that are given back by the query.

Just added it to the maven configuration section and it worked.

```
      <schemaPattern>dbo</schemaPattern>
      <exportBeans>true</exportBeans>
```

Comment: Good that you found it. The exportBeans parameter is also mentioned in the docs, but should be maybe highlighted more http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/3.6.6/reference/html_single/#sql_integration